# Flask-appbuilder problems when try to redirect a form

Tags: python, flask

I'm having fun with flask and flask-appbuilder module and I have one problem which I can't resolve. I have this piece of code in my views.py:

```
from flask.ext.appbuilder import AppBuilder, BaseView, expose, has_access, SimpleFormView
from flask_appbuilder._compat import as_unicode
from app import appbuilder
from wtforms import Form, StringField, BooleanField, TextField, SelectMultipleField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from flask_appbuilder.fieldwidgets import BS3TextFieldWidget, DatePickerWidget
from flask.ext.appbuilder.forms import DynamicForm

from flask.ext.babelpkg import lazy_gettext as _
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateField
from flask import flash, send_file, redirect, url_for
from scripts.create_excel import excelstuff


class MyView(BaseView):
    default_view = 'method1'

    @expose('/method1/')
    @has_access
    def method1(self):
        # do something with param1
        # and return to previous page or index
        return 'Hello'

    @expose('/method2/<string:param1>')
    @has_access
    def method2(self, param1):
        # do something with param1
        # and render template with param
        param1 = 'Goodbye %s' % (param1)
        return param1

    @expose('/method3/<string:param1>')
    @has_access
    def method3(self, param1):
        # do something with param1
        # and render template with param
        param1 = 'Goodbye %s' % (param1)
        self.update_redirect()
        return self.render_template('method3.html',
                                    param1=param1)

    @expose('/download/<string:filename>')
    @has_access

    def download(filename):
        return send_file(appbuilder.app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + filename,
                         as_attachment=True)


# Forms
class MyForm(DynamicForm):
    field1 = StringField(('Field1'),
                         description=('Your field number one!'),
                         validators=[DataRequired()], widget=BS3TextFieldWidget())
    field2 = StringField(('Field2'),
                         description=('Your field number two!'), widget=BS3TextFieldWidget())
    start = DateField('Start Date', format='%Y-%m-%d', validators=[DataRequired()], widget=DatePickerWidget())
    end = DateField('Start Date', format='%Y-%m-%d', validators=[DataRequired()], widget=DatePickerWidget())
    project1 = SelectMultipleField('Projects', choices=[('1', 'Choice1'), ('2', 'Choice2'), ('3', 'Choice3')],
                                   coerce=unicode, validators=[DataRequired()])
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()], widget=BS3TextFieldWidget())


class MyFormView(SimpleFormView):
    default_view = 'this_form_get'
    form = MyForm
    form_title = 'This is my first form view'

    message = 'My form submitted'

    def form_post(self, form):
        # process form
        flash(as_unicode(form.field1.data), 'info')
        excelstuff(as_unicode(form.field1.data))
        return redirect(url_for('myview.download', filename='demo.xlsx'))




appbuilder.add_view(MyFormView, "My form View", icon="fa-group", label=_('My form View'),
                    category="My Forms", category_icon="fa-cogs")
appbuilder.add_view(MyView, "Method1", category='My View')
appbuilder.add_link("Method2", href='/myview/method2/john', category='My View')
appbuilder.add_link("Method3", href='/myview/method3/john', category='My View')
```

I sending my form and I executing another python function which creates an xls file with content sent by the form, but I don't know how can I do to redirect to this xls file and download it, this is the specific piece of code:

```
def form_post(self, form):
        # process form
        flash(as_unicode(form.field1.data), 'info')
        excelstuff(as_unicode(form.field1.data))
        return redirect(url_for('myview.download', filename='demo.xlsx'))
```

Comment: Whats the error your getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

1 - url_for is casesensitive, so do it like this:

```
return redirect(url_for('MyView.download', filename='demo.xlsx'))
```

2 - SimpleFormView.form_post is just for form processing the answer is made by the framework, so in this case you should override 'this_form_post'

```
@expose("/form", methods=['POST'])
@has_access
def this_form_post(self):
    self._init_vars()
    form = self.form.refresh()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(as_unicode(form.field1.data), 'info')
        excelstuff(as_unicode(form.field1.data))
        return redirect(url_for('MyView.download', filename='demo.xlsx'))
    else:
        widgets = self._get_edit_widget(form=form)
        return self.render_template(
            self.form_template,
            title=self.form_title,
            widgets=widgets,
            appbuilder=self.appbuilder
        )
```

I Have not tested it, tell me if it worked.